# TestNG cross browser test fails after launcing first browser

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-ide, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run some basic test on different browsers but the test are failing once after the launching the first browser (in this case Firefox) and fails to execute the Chrome and IE browsers.

Java code using TestNG annotations -

```
package com.Selenium_Practice;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import junit.framework.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.opera.OperaDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;

public class CrossBrowserTestingUsingTestNG {

WebDriver driver;
ExtentReports report = ExtentReports.get(CrossBrowserTestingUsingTestNG.class);

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Test
@Parameters("browser")
public void CrossBrowserCodeBrowser(String browserName){

    report.init("E:\\Report\\CrossBrowserTestingUsingTestNG.html", true);
    report.startTest("Starting the test for CrossBrowserTestingUsingTestNG class");


    if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")){
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      report.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Firefox browser is up and running");
    }//if

    else if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){
      System.setProperty("webDriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
      driver = new ChromeDriver();  
      report.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Chrome browser is up and runnning");
    }//else if

    else if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")){
      System.setProperty("webDriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Driver\\IEDriverServer.exe");
      driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
      report.log(LogStatus.INFO, "IE is up and running");
    }//else if

    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747315/getting-nullpointerexception-when-trying-to-generate-test-reports-using-extentre/31752389#31752389");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='question-header']/h1/a")).getAttribute("href");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='question-header']/h1/a")).getTagName();
    System.out.println("Link : "+driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='question-header']/h1/a")).getAttribute("href"));
    System.out.println("Question : "+driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='question-header']/h1/a")).getTagName());
    Assert.assertEquals("a", driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='question-header']/h1/a")).getTagName());
    report.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Both are equal");
    report.endTest();
    driver.quit();
 }//CrossBrowserCodeBrowser

}//CrossBrowserTestingUsingTestNG
```

Test Suit -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="CrossBrowserTesting" parallel="none">

 <test name="FirefoxTestSuit">    
  <classes>
    <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/> 
   <class name="com.Selenium_Practice.CrossBrowserTestingUsingTestNG"/>  
 </classes>  
</test> <!-- CrossBrowser -->

<test name="ChromeTestSuit">  
  <classes>
   <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/> 
    <class name="com.Selenium_Practice.CrossBrowserTestingUsingTestNG"/>  
  </classes>  
</test> <!-- CrossBrowser -->

<test name="IETestSuit">
 <classes>
   <parameter name="browser" value="ie"/>
    <class name="com.Selenium_Practice.CrossBrowserTestingUsingTestNG"/>
  </classes>
 </test> <!-- CrossBrowser -->

</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

After running the XML file using TestNG i am getting the following results -

```
[TestNG] Running:
 D:\Java Programs and files\com.Selenium_Practice\CrossBrowsertestng.xml

 log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger  (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
 log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
 log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig  for more info.
 Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747315/getting-nullpointerexception-when-trying-to-generate-test-reports-using-extentre
 Question : a
 Aug 01, 2015 6:28:10 AM  org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog destroyHarder
 INFO: Command failed to close cleanly. Destroying forcefully (v2).   org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog@1503f6b

 ===============================================
 CrossBrowserTesting
 Total tests run: 3, Failures: 2, Skips: 0
 ===============================================
```

Updated XML file -
In the below XML file i put the parameters outside the classes.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
 <suite name="CrossBrowserTesting" parallel="none">

 <test name="FirefoxTestSuit">  
  <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>  
   <classes>
    <class name="com.Selenium_Practice.CrossBrowserTestingUsingTestNG"/>  
   </classes>  
  </test> <!-- CrossBrowser -->

  <test name="ChromeTestSuit">  
   <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/> 
    <classes>
     <class name="com.Selenium_Practice.CrossBrowserTestingUsingTestNG"/>  
    </classes>  
   </test> <!-- CrossBrowser -->

<test name="IETestSuit">
 <parameter name="browser" value="ie"/>
  <classes>
    <class name="com.Selenium_Practice.CrossBrowserTestingUsingTestNG"/>
  </classes>
 </test> <!-- CrossBrowser -->  
 </suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Output -
After running the changed xmfile i am getting same result.

```
 [TestNG] Running:
  D:\Java Programs and files\com.Selenium_Practice\CrossBrowsertestng.xml

 log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
 log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
 log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
 Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747315/getting-nullpointerexception-when-trying-to-generate-test-reports-using-extentre
 Question : a
 Aug 02, 2015 12:29:54 PM  org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog destroyHarder
 INFO: Command failed to close cleanly. Destroying forcefully (v2).  org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog@1be3395

 ===============================================
 CrossBrowserTesting
 Total tests run: 3, Failures: 2, Skips: 0
 ===============================================
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parameter tag should be outside classes.

```
<test name="FirefoxTestSuit">  
<parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>   
  <classes>
     <class name="com.Selenium_Practice.CrossBrowserTestingUsingTestNG"/>  
 </classes>  
</test> <!-- CrossBrowser -->
```

Comment: I put the paramenter outside the classes but again after executing first class its failing for other two i.e, Firefox is executing but Chrome and IE is failing.

Comment: Please update your latest testng xml in question and also paste error your are getting.

Comment: webDriver.chrome.driver -> it should be webdriver.chrome.driver  .                             Driver 'D' should be in lowercase. Same for IE.